# What does "run to the left" mean exactly in the context of politics?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I was reading a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Wu) when I ran into this passage:

> Wu and Teachout ran against Andrew Cuomo, the incumbent governor, and Kathy Hochul, an upstate Democrat and former Representative in the House. Teachout and Wu **ran to the left of** Cuomo and Hochul. Hochul won the race for Lieutenant Governor; Wu took 40% of the popular vote.

Intuitively I understood **left** to mean *Left politics* as in *the left wing*. From the context, however, it seems the sentence in question is saying Teachout and Wu lost to Cuomo and Hochul. So does **run to the left of** mean *be beat by*? Does **left** carry the sense of *not as good as*?

If **left** here indeed refers to the political left, is "run to someone's left" idiomatic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a meaning of "to run" that is particular to politics or any position of office.

> run
>
> 26 : to be a candidate for office She ran for mayor.
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/run

E.g.

> Trump and Clinton both ran for president in 2016.

or

> Trump and Clinton both ran for the presidency in 2016.

If X runs to the left of Y, it just means the X's politics are more left-wing than Y's and they are both running for office in the same contest.

Comment: Candidates are said both **to stand for office** and **to run for office**. The expressions mean the same thing. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53070/does-one-run-or-stand-for-election